# SD card creating "extra" file?

Tags: sd-card, sd, sd.h

So, maybe I'm too tired to see the obvious issue here, but my SD card script is causing a "blank" file to be created, then a secondary file to be correctly created.

I'm trying to store data logs, and I don't want to overwrite old logs, I just want to "move" them to the back of the queue.  So I start with six files on the SD card:

> DATA.TXT
>   DATA~1.TXT
>   DATA~2.TXT
>   DATA~3.TXT
>   DATA~4.TXT
>   DATA~5.TXT

Everything writes to `DATA.TXT`, and `DATA~1.TXT` through `DATA~5.TXT` are "old" logs, from oldest to newest.  This means that, the next time I boot up the Arduino, I want the contents of `DATA.TXT` to be read into a new file called `DATA~6.TXT`, I want the old `DATA.TXT` to be deleted, and I want a new `DATA.TXT` to be created for the rest of the program.  It should look like this:

> DATA.TXT     <=== New, blank file, primed for logging new data
>   DATA~1.TXT
>   DATA~2.TXT
>   DATA~3.TXT
>   DATA~4.TXT
>   DATA~5.TXT
>   DATA~6.TXT   <=== "Old" DATA.TXT

In reality, it's creating two files: instead of `DATA~6.TXT` holding the contents it should, it's blank -- and a file called `DATA~7.TXT` is created with the contents of the "old" `DATA.TXT`.  After that, it's writing to the "new" `DATA.TXT` as it should.  Something is lost (or added) in shifting the data, for some reason, looking like this:

> DATA.TXT     <=== New, blank file, primed for logging new data
>   DATA~1.TXT
>   DATA~2.TXT
>   DATA~3.TXT
>   DATA~4.TXT
>   DATA~5.TXT
>   DATA~6.TXT   <=== Blank, unused "new" file?
>   DATA~7.TXT   <=== "Old" DATA.TXT

**EDIT:** Each file contains test data ( e.g. - file `DATA~1.TXT` contains a line like `This is "DATA~1.TXT"`) So I can track which files are "moved," and where they go. That's how I know where the "old" `DATA.TXT` file is going, and how I know `DATA~6.TXT` is "blank." It's actually a blank file, with no data in it.

**EDIT #2:** As stated in the comments below, the Uno doesn't actually wait for a serial connection.  I just tested this, and it is true... that being said: I'm still getting a blank `DATA~6.TXT` and `DATA.TXT` is being moved into `DATA~7.TXT` without cause.

Now that you know the goal, and (probably) see the issue, here's the code:

```cpp
/*
 * Tests the SD card slot, assuring no functional code is missing
 * for BIB process to correctly log data.
 *
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

String fileName = "DATA.TXT";                       // Declare a filename with FAT 8.3 naming conventions
File dataLog;                                       // Store our "opened" file in an object

void setup(){
    Serial.begin( 115200 );
    while( !Serial ){                               // Wait for serial port to open before doing anything
    }

    Serial.println( "\nInitializing SD card..." );  // Start SD card
    if( !SD.begin( 4 ) ){
        Serial.println( "Initialization failed!" );
        while( 1 );
    }
    Serial.println( "Initialization done." );

    Serial.println( "\nChecking if we have a unique filename..." );
    if( SD.exists( fileName ) )                     // Give our data log a unique filename if the current filename already exists
        moveFiles();

    dataLog = SD.open( fileName, FILE_WRITE );      // Open our file for editing if it doesn't already exist
    Serial.println( "Created save file!" );

    // Write to file the first time
    if( dataLog ){
        Serial.println( "\nWriting int test to file..." );
        dataLog.println( "Testing Sequence1..." );
        dataLog.println( "\tSequence1 complete." );
        Serial.println( "\tFirst test written!" );
        dataLog.close();
        Serial.println( "\tData log closed." );
    }
    else
        Serial.println( "---Error opening data log file!---" );
}

void loop(){
}

// Moves the last `DATA.TXT` to `DATA~x.TXT` where `x` is the largest integer.
// This makes the "highest" numbered file the last data log, and `DATA.TXT` the current data log.
// Follows SFN8.3 standards of naming, with 8 chars for filename, 4 chars for extension, and preceeding
// periods converted to `~` chars.
// This leaves us with only 999 possible "backup" data logs.
void moveFiles(){
    bool sdCardFull = false;                            // Keep track of if our SD card is "full" or not
    byte num = 1;
    File newFile;

    String existingFile = String( "DATA~" ) + String( num ) + String( ".TXT" );     // Creates a filename of `DATA~num.TXT` to test

    // Check if this filename exists, too.  Iterate `num` to avoid overwriting currently existing files
    while( SD.exists( existingFile ) ){
        if( num == 999 ){          // If the SD card is full
            sdCardFull = true;
            noMoreRoom( sdCardFull );
        }

        num++;
        existingFile = String( "DATA~" ) + String( num ) + String( ".TXT" );
    }

    dataLog = SD.open( fileName );
    // Create the new file, with the new filename
    newFile = SD.open( existingFile, FILE_WRITE );

    // Move the old data log into the new filename
    while( dataLog.available() )
        newFile.write( dataLog.read() );

    // Close, remove, then re-open the data log
    newFile.close();
    dataLog.close();
    SD.remove( fileName );                          // Deletes the old data log
}

// We cannot find a good filename for the SFN8.3 format, since all of the available filenames have been
// used up, so we will stop the program from running until the SD card is cleaned up, before we "destroy"
// the last backup file.
void noMoreRoom( bool sdCardFull ){
    /*
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 0 );
    lcd.print( "   SD card is   " );
    lcd.setCursor( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print( "   too full!!   " );
    */

    Serial.println( "The SD card is full and we will not proceed until it is cleaned up." );

    while( sdCardFull ){}       // Do absolutely nothing until the SD card is "cleaned up"
}
```

Comment: Let me guess... you plug the board in (or program the board), then you open the serial terminal, and the program "starts running"...?  What about the period between plugging it in (or programming it) and you opening the serial terminal? It runs then too you know... (assuming an Uno - but you don't specify which board you are using...)

Comment: Yes, it's an Uno... and a Nano... and a Pro-Mini.  And the sketch should be caught in the `while( !Serial )` loop until the Serial Monitor is attached, right?

Comment: No, that line is only for native USB boards as I remember. It will not wait for anything on an Uno or Nano

Comment: Maybe you should first test for the file to actually contain data, before you move it.

Comment: `while (!Serial)` works only for MCU with native USB (32u4, SAMD), not for Uno, Nano, Mega, Mini. Uno & co. reset on new connection. they start to run and then they are reset on new connection

Comment: All files contain data with their respective filenames ( e.g. - `File "DATA~1.TXT"` ).  They're being moved correctly.  That's how I know that `DATA~6.TXT` is blank.

Comment: Even if the MCU runs without delay, `DATA.TXT` should still be going to `DATA~6.TXT`, a new `DATA.TXT` should be created with the "test data" per the code, then the Serial Monitor should reset things, moving the "test data" file to `DATA~7.TXT` and duplicate "test data" to `DATA.TXT`, right? But this isn't happening... I still can't explain what's happening.

Comment: Do you also see that behavior with a complete new setup? (Meaning all files deleted, letting the code start from the known startpoint) Maybe the Arduino was once interrupted by a reset, before he could write the actual data to the file

Comment: On a fresh setup (formatted SD card with no files on it), I get two files: `DATA.TXT` and `DATA~1.TXT`, with both having the "test sequence data" written to both.  Other than filename, they're identical, according to `cmp` and `md5sum`.  I'm still not 100% sure why it's creating two files... usually one is blank, but they're identical in this instance.

Comment: You can do multiple resets, by pressing the reset button or reopening the serial monitor, to check, if it works under the correct circumstances. A reset during writing to the SD card can lead to corrupt data. Maybe it is suitable to disable the reset from serial by adding a capacitor between Reset and ground. That prevents the serial interface to reset the microcontroller. Though it also prevents programming, so you would have to remove the capacitor again for programming

Comment: try to use `-` instead of `~`

Comment: @Juraj I was following the [SFN8.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) format, which is recommended by [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SDCardNotes).  It **should** work with the `~`, but it **should** also work with the `-` as well.  Trying both, neither are producing the desired outcome.